# eclipse version require specifc Apache Tomcat server

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

My point is that every eclipse ide contains a specific javax.servlet-api version. So, does it need specific tomcat server? For example if I am using Eclipse Indigo, will I be able to run it on Tomcat 5.5 or do I have to use Tomcat 7.0?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean when you say that Eclipse contains a specific servlet-api version?

Using the [WTP](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools) you can define different servers and versions, even at the same time. You can set the servlet version when adding the "dynamic web project" facet to the project (but you can't change it easily later). So it is no problem to use Tomcat 5.5 with Eclipse Indigo.

Comment: I am new to this stuff,so i don't know what do you mean by WTP please provide me link  to link where i get a detailed explanation related to server. Thanks in advance.